# Why does this template code compile?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm working on a large project, which contains a section of code that compiles - but I don't understand how. I distilled it down to this simple example:

```
template <typename T>
struct First {
    typedef int type;           // (A)
    typename T::Three order;    // (B)
};

template <typename T> struct Second {
    typedef typename T::type type;
};


template <typename T> struct Third {
    int val;
    T two;
};

struct Traits {
    typedef First<Traits> One;
    typedef Second<One> Two;
    typedef Third<Two> Three;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Traits::One x;
};
```

The class `First` is templated on `Traits` and references `Traits::Three`, which itself is a `typedef` based on `Two`, which is a `typedef` based on `First<Traits>`... hence it is circular. But this code compiles fine on both gcc4.6 and VC10. However, if I flip the ordering of the two lines marked `(A)` and `(B)`, the code does not compile, complaining about the `typedef` inside of `Second`.

Why does this code compile, and why is it that the ordering of the `typedef` and the member variable matters?

Comment: Try to draw it on paper in a tree this way: make a node for each definition, and for each (forward) declaration of the types, and then draw edges for which needs a full definition and which needs a declaration only, and you will see that it won't be circular.

Comment: Hi - unrelated, but do you know if P0704 is a DR against 17?

Comment: @Kerrek No idea, I don't even know how such things are decided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of things worth saying.

- The code will break if `Second` is modified to contain

  ```
  T badObject;
  ```

  with a long "instantiated from..." chain and ending with an "incomplete type" error, due to the circularity you expect, but not if you instead add

  ```
  typename T::type object;
  ```

  This is telling you that the compiler is cleverly observing it **doesn't need to completely encapsulate `T`**, only to know what `T::type` is. To illustrate this, note you can legally have

  ```
  First { ... typedef T type; ... }
  Second { typename T::type object; }
  ```

  since T contains no currently-being-defined *objects*, or

  ```
  First { ... typedef typename T::One type; ... }
  Second { typedef typename T::type object; }
  ```

  since the `typedef` in `Second` does not require an instance of any objects either - but **not**, say,

  ```
  First { ... typedef typename T::One type; ... }
  Second { typename T::type object; }
  ```

  since only then is the compiler is actually required to nest a `First<Traits>` object within a `First<Traits>` object.
- The issue with swapping (A) and (B) is that the clever trick the compiler pulled above is working by introducing a new copy of the definition of each specialized template, parsing it **one line at a time**. The error occurs if it hasn't got as far as the type definition in `First` when it is required to know it by `Second`.

Comment: Great thank you, this is perfect. I did not realize the compiler could go one line at a time.

Comment: I haven't checked the specification, but I assume that this is the only possible issue. If you think about it, you already knew that things happen line by line - that's why `class A {}; class B : A;` and `class B : A; class A {};` are different!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a complete type for a `typedef`.

Comment: But this doesn't compile:

    `template <typename Derived>
    struct Foo {
        typedef typename Derived::type type;
    };

    struct Bar : public Foo<Bar> {
        typedef int type;
    };

    int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        Bar b;
    }`

Comment: @Barry: The difference is that `Bar` needs the definition of `Foo<Bar>` (due to inheritance) and the `typedef` inside `Foo` does not refer to `Bar`, but to a nested type. A nested type is a *member*, and the enclosing type must be complete.

Answer (score 1):

You've accepted an answer that was far better than the one I provided - so I'm removing mine. However, I thought you might be interested in a further reduction to your example. I have marked two lines as A and B to correlate back to your original code. If you flip them, then just as in your example, compilation will fail.

```
 template<typename T>
 struct First
 {
      typedef typename T::type type;
 };

 struct Second
 {
      typedef int type;    // (A)
      First<Second> order; // (B)
 };


 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
      Second x;
 };
```